# How to run regex on webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, block

I'm trying to make a bit of a crude ad-blocker with javascript
The code I currently have:

```
var pattern = '<iframe(.*?)</iframe>|<object(.*?)</object>';

if (document.body.parentNode.innerHTML.match(pattern)) 
{
    document.body.parentNode.innerHTML =
        document.body.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(pattern, '<b>AD BLOCKED</b>');
}
```

The problem is that the page reloads. Is there a way I can stop the page from reloading? (My main target is adsense)

Comment: Does the page reload or the `iframe`?

Comment: Also [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) requires a `RegExp` object, not just a string.

Comment: @blurd strings will work too

Comment: @Joeytje50 Ah, didn't know.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm a complete noob, but will it replace EACH instance, or will it replace only the first instance?

Comment: In JavaScript, regex is denoted /.../ not '...'

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem right, since you're just wanting to replace the html on the page.  I can't imagine what that will do.  To answer your [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) question, though, try this.

```
var pattern = /<iframe.*<\/iframe>/gi;
document.body.innerHTML = 
    document.body.innerHTML.replace(pattern, '<strong>bye iframe</strong>');
```

`replace()` will swap out all the matches found by the `RegExp` with the second parameter.

`/<iframe.*<\/iframe>/` is a **regular expression** matching anything within **iframe** tags.
`gi` modifies the regex telling it to be global and case-insensitive.

Again, you will probably have some unexpected behavior rewriting the innerHTML of the body, so I'd rethink your approach.  Perhaps you could use jQuery to find the tags you don't want and hide or remove them. ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/R7g55/))